# Quacks of Quedlingburg Crow Skull Set 2 Keep Drawing

Tags: quacks

The Crow Skull Set 2 bonus allows you to receive Victory points and Coins even if your pot explodes within the next 1/2/4 draws.

Does this mean you can make that full number of draws even if your pot explodes straight away?

To be clear, I draw a 4 value blue chip, then the next chip is white taking me over 7 Cherry Bombs. Can I draw and place the next 3 'safe' chips anyway?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No you can't continue to draw after your pot explodes.

The only ability listed for the Crow Skull set 2 is that you receive both victory points and coins if your pot explodes in the next 1/2/4 draws - it says nothing about allowing you to continue to draw after your pot explodes.

Thus the normal rules for stopping when your pot explodes would still apply.